# datatype mismatching in criteria expression while using vb.net with ms access as db

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

pls explian me why this error occurs

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    dp = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    src = "Data source=c:\Database\licdb.mdb"        
    con.ConnectionString = dp & src
    con.Open()

    query = "select * from year2008 where id = '" & id & "'"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
    da.Fill(ds1, "tab")
    TextBox1.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(0)
    TextBox2.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(1)
    TextBox3.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(2)
    TextBox4.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(3)
    TextBox5.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(4)
    TextBox14.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(5)
    TextBox7.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(6)
    TextBox8.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(7)
    TextBox9.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(8)
    TextBox10.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(9)
    TextBox16.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(10)
    TextBox11.Text = ds1.Tables("tab").Rows(id).Item(11)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: When you request help with an error, you have to provide accurate information to get help quickly. For example: line of the error, contents of the involved variables (what is "id"?), etc.

Comment: Seems unlikely that id is a string, so the single quotes you've wrapped it in are the issue. That said you should be using parameterised queries anyway. A using statement would be good as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "id" is not defined in the code here. Probably the problem is that the type of the variable "id" is not the same type as the column "id" the database. If variable "id" is not numeric, and table column "id" is a numeric data type, then it will cause this error.

You can check the variable "id" to make sure it has a numeric value:

```
if isnumeric(id) then...
```